# How to check if a number is even?

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that checks for even. However, when I perform querying, it always returns false. I'm new to prolog, and I'm really puzzled by this behavior

```
Even(N):- N mod 2 = 0.
```

**Update:**
If I change it to `Even(N):- 0 is N mod 2.`, then it works. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the proper operators and have some typos! First, the name of the predicate starts with a small letter (`even` instead of `Even`). Operator for the equality comparison is `=:=` (you are using `=` that is for unification! and `is` to apply a value to a variable. Although what you right means `0 is 0` for the even numbers and works here but in some situation will be failed. See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) to know more about this.).

```
even(N):- mod(N,2) =:= 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is for unification and `=:=` nd is are considered equals to in Prolog. It's as simple as that. Also, whether it's a rule or fact, it always starts so that the code will be:

```
even(N):-
    mod(N,2) =:= 0.
```